# flask-admin basic example throws builtins.AttributeError exception

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am following flask-admin's Quick Start guide ([link](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.7/quickstart/#initialization)) and just tried running the basic example provided under the Initialization [section](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.7/quickstart/#initialization). When I run that code and browse to localhost:5000/admin/ I get the following error

**builtins.AttributeError**

AttributeError: 'For' object has no attribute 'test'

There is a detailed exception stack I can paste as well if helpful.

I suspected a dependency is missing and trying reinstalling flask-admin, but it didn't help. Here's my pip freeze output:

```
$ pip freeze
APScheduler==3.3.1
click==6.7
dominate==2.3.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.0
Flask-APScheduler==1.7.0
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.13
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.32.14
tzlocal==1.4
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

I'm using python 3.6.1

My code is exactly as in the example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin

app = Flask(__name__)

admin = Admin(app)

app.run()
```

And this is the exception stack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 69, in inner
        return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 368, in _run_view
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 452, in index
        return self.render(self._template)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 308, in render
        return render_template(template, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
        context, ctx.app)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
        rv = template.render(context)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
        return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\templates\bootstrap2\admin\index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\templates\bootstrap2\admin\master.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends admin_base_template %}
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 543, in _generate
        optimized=self.optimized)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 82, in generate
        generator.visit(node)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
        return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 772, in visit_Template
        self.blockvisit(block.body, block_frame)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 372, in blockvisit
        self.visit(node, frame)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
        return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 1130, in visit_If
        self.blockvisit(node.body, if_frame)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 372, in blockvisit
        self.visit(node, frame)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
        return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\project\.venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 1014, in visit_For
        if node.test:
    AttributeError: 'For' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please provide the code and the exception.

Comment: @stamaimer - updated the question, added code + exception stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I messed up my venv somehow. I tried again with a brand new venv, installed all packages and now everything works fine. Hope this helps someone.